# null pointer exception when attempting to clear shared preferences in android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I keep getting a null pointer exception when attempting to clear my shared prefernces, Is there anything with my code that sticks out as obviously wrong? thanks in advance!

```
prefs1 = context.getSharedPreferences(APPLICATION_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
finish();
```

Comment: can you please attach the Log about this exception? Anyway this is a working (official) example about how to use them: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref I hope it will help you

Comment: sorry I forgot to point out that the log cat said my variable prefs1 is what is returning null, here is the full message 01-07 07:48:49.512: E/AndroidRuntime(2349):  at com.testapp2.second.activities.Testapp2Activity.onOptionsItemSelected(Testapp2Activity.java:103)

Comment: should the first line be declared in the onCreate perhaps?

Comment: context.getSharedPreferences is not documented to return null. Start posting the whole code + the whole logcat in your main post, otherwise we cant help you!

Comment: yes please update and put everything on the first post or it results a bit messy and we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

if first line is exception then check value of APPLICATION_PREFERENCES it may be null.